# GPG error in Ubuntu update

Tags: apt, security, ppa, proxy, launchpad

When I run the sudo apt-get update, it results in the following

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
 W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 551CE2FB4CBEDD5A
 W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
```

By googling I came to know the key is missing, and it can be obtained by running the following command with the corresponding hexadecimal numbers

```
 saikirangvr@ubuntu:~$ sudo gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv 551CE2FB4CBEDD5A
```

But I was not able to fix this as this gave me the error

```
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on configuration file `/home/saikirangvr/.gnupg/gpg.conf'
gpg: external program calls are disabled due to unsafe options file permissions
gpg: keyserver communications error: general error
gpg: keyserver receive failed: general error
```

I tried many times but I was unable to fix. I was behind a proxy server in my college and I have configured the Ubuntu well to use behind the proxy.

After using

```
 sudo chown -R saikirangvr:saikirangvr /home/saikirangvr/.gnupg
```

the problem of unsafe ownership was gone, and it gave the following....

```
 sai@ubuntu:~/gpgpu-sim/ispass2009-benchmarks$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1E9377A2BA9EF27F 
 gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
 gpgkeys: key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F not found on keyserver
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
 gpg: Total number processed: 0
 sai@ubuntu:~/gpgpu-sim/ispass2009-benchmarks$ gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
 gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
 gpgkeys: key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F not found on keyserver
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
 gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

the result of adding the ppa

```
sai@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
[sudo] password for sai: 
Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8: Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'
```

same error occurs when using launch pad get keys

```
 sai@ubuntu:~$ sudo launchpad-getkeys

 Please wait... launchpad-getkeys is running an update so 
 it can detect the missing GPG keys

 Trying to import all the missing keys
 gpg: requesting key 4C9D234C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
 gpgkeys: key 531EE72F4C9D234C not found on keyserver
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
 gpg: Total number processed: 0
 gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
 gpgkeys: key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F not found on keyserver
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
 gpg: Total number processed: 0

 launchpad-getkeys has finished importing all missing GPG keys. 
 Try running sudo apt-get update - you shouldn't see any key 
  errors anymore
```

What is the problem. **Is there any other method to solve this like through GUI **.......

Comment: you might have done a mistake similar to me.
While installing Maven, I followed steps mentioned here:
http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/05/install-apache-maven-3-2-1-ubuntu-14-04/
except the last step i.e. "Step 5: Remove PPA from sources.list"
As a result of this I was getting GPG error similar to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
```

Once installed, to import all the missing GPG keys for your PPAs, simply use the following command:

```
$ sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

It will run an update and try to import all missing GPG keys for you. After executing it, hope you don't see any GPG errors.

The 

[link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html) is a reference to the solution.

Comment: tried the link http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/launchpad-getkeys-gets-proxy-support.html but got the error sudo: launchpad-getkeys: command not found

Comment: first u need to add repository, then run apt-get update so that package list can be updated, thereafter u need to install launchpad-getkeys. I too use internet connection that is behind proxy but it works fine for me.

Comment: I have updated the question with the errors I got, can you please help me.......

Answer (score 1):

Fix the ownership of the `.gnupg` directory:

```
sudo chown -R saikirangvr:saikirangvr /home/saikirangvr/.gnupg
```

After that repeat the key importing command.

By the way, the `gpg` command has to be issued without `sudo`, in this way you will not break your file's ownership.

Comment: It gave the following result for all the three keys I required.....gpg: requesting key BA9EF27F from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
gpgkeys: key 1E9377A2BA9EF27F not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

Comment: I followed the link ......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112400/gpgkeys-key-7f0ceb10-not-found-on-keyserver-while-installing-mongodb-on-ubunt ,and gave me the error gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'keyserver.ubuntu.com' can you please help me...

Comment: Try this: gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv  1E9377A2BA9EF27F

Comment: The gpg key import has to be done without sudo!

Comment: The same continued and Got this error on update Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/launchpad.net/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found, I browsed through the link and also didn't found it

Comment: Did you issued `sudo apt-get update` after gpg import?

Comment: the command,gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 1E9377A2BA9EF27F which you have mentioned didn't work and after I run update which gave 404 error......

Comment: I have update the question with the errors I got, can you please help me.......