# Ubuntu 17.04 Update Issue

Tags: apt, updates, 17.04

I get this error when I try to update my Ubuntu 17.04. I already tried few solutions but nothing worked so far. I get these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
W: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/342560/507051) help?

Comment: looks like you're trying to update from 12.04 (precise), which reach it's end of life the 28th April 2017, to 17.04 (zesty)? i'd suggest that you do 12.04 LTS -> 14.04 LTS -> 16.04 LTS -> 17.04, or better yet, a clean installation (which i'd guess would be less troublesome). upgrade notes: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

Comment: What *exactly* did you do to provoke this output? What were you trying to achieve? I don't see any error messages by the way, just warning and notices.

Comment: finally i fixed the problem by edit ` /etc/apt/sources.list`  I'm already use ubuntu 17.4 see salution :) @KrisStadler @David Foerster @mgor

Comment: Nice one @Shroog! Can you please post your solution here for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

run this command to baukup ur sourses.list ..

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`

then go to this page [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

then pickup ur country  and ur release of ubuntu then Generate listafter that 
copy and past it after run this command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

last command `sudo apt-get update`

Have fun !