# How to reset the repositories present in "Other Software" tab of "Software and Updates" in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, software-center, mysql

I was googling out steps to update MySQL from 5 to 8 version. Without further thinking I inserted these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

The keyserver of Ubuntu 12 version was added. So later I manually removed them from the "*Other Software*" tab of "*Software and Updates*".

Somehow it got better, but whenever I insert the command `sudo apt-get update`, it ends with the below-given error:

```
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details
```

Terminal when `sudo apt-get update` was inserted:

[image]

I'm still not able to find a solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: okay. I'll avoid this kind of mistakes next time on wards @pomsky

Comment: You can also **[edit]** and fix the current one.

Comment: Please show also `apt-key list`

Comment: I found the solution. I reset all the links using [Ubuntu Sources Link Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/). I referred to this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948607/ubuntu-17-04-update-issue) (which I was not able to find it earlier)